# R or python implementation of sparse PCA for p>n

Tags: r, pca, python, sparse

According to [this paper](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAC&url=http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/spc_jcgs.pdf&ei=gaWdUpTLDKHH7AaRkIGoBg&usg=AFQjCNH5mw9Fbq3eAwDtpsJNtMLr_BedCw&bvm=bv.57155469,d.ZGU), there are 2 algorithms to perform sparse PCA. One is better if $p>n$. I need to run SPCA on a $2000\times12000$ matrix so I am looking for an implementation of this algorithm. There is an sparse PCA implementation in sklearn and one in the R package `elasticnet` but I think they are the $n>p$ version.

Where can I find an implementation of this algorithm?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcaPP/pcaPP.pdf OR   http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PMA/PMA.pdf

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about looking for an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the standard sparse PCA algorithm and increase the ridge penalty coefficient.

There are probably better solutions but this is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [nsprcomp](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nsprcomp) package for R. It implements sparse and/or non-negative PCA and is efficient for $p \gg n$ because it only uses the data matrix and not the covariance matrix. A comparison to `arrayspc` from the `elasticnet` package is given in [this blog post](https://sigg-iten.ch/learningbits/2013/09/15/non-negative-sparse-pca-comparison/).

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Scikit-Learn's implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.SparsePCA.html) and see if it matches what you are looking for.

I don't know about the $n<p$ constraint, but it might be worth trying out and looking at the performance either way.